# setting html values on separate page with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How would you set the html values of one page from another after running an ajax call?
I want to run the ajax call, based on this information, set the values of another page then jump to that new page.
I'm using `window.location.href` to jump to my new page and `$.post()` to run the ajax call.

I've looked at `.load()` and it might be what I need to use and I just didn't read the documentation carefully

Comment: You can't set the values of any page that doesn't yet exist - only the current one that the browser is viewing. If you want to send data between pages, research about querystring, localstorage or sessionstorage.

Comment: So first of all, when you're reloading a page you're reloading all of the javascript you have linked to it - so this would not be a good way to send data from page to page. The way that you do this is with your web server and we'll need more details to help you.

Comment: oh right. I should probably set the cookie or something then load the page. thanks

Comment: You would use AJAX to call a PHP script that rewrites the second page.

Comment: You can use AJAX to send details to a PHP page that can then load those values into a Session. Then when you load the next page, you can make use of the session data. We need to see more of your working code or what you have tried to help any further.